# How to pass lat / long values from a google maps infowindow to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a relatively simple Google Maps implementation. It requests the user's geoposition information from the browser and (a) geocodes it, (b) pulls N nearest location records from a database (currently max 20 locations within 25 miles), (c) plots the user's location and the location records as markers, with information about the location (address, etc.) stored as a contentString to be viewed in the infowindow.

[Screenshot](http://johnacraft.com/images/private/screenshot.png)

What I want to do is pass the lat / lon values for the location to a javascript function that gets directions and plots them on the map. My thought was to include them as a form as part of the contentString:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="' + location[i].latitude + ' name="sitelat"/>
<input type="hidden" value="' + location[i].longitude + ' name="sitelon"/>
<input type="button" onClick="GetDirs()" value="Directions">
</form>
```

which would be retrieved in the function:

```
function GetDirs()
{
    var userlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(userlat, userlon)

    sitelat = document.getElementById(sitelat);
    sitelon = document.getElementById(sitelon);

    var sitelatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(sitelat, sitelon)

    // continue to get directions from userlatlng to sitelatlng

} //GetDirs
```

There are 700 records in the database, any 20 of which could be populated on the map at any given time, all of which have 'sitelat' and 'sitelon' properties in the contentString.

My mental block is how to write one function that retrieves the lat / lon from the correct infowindow. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't even need a form, just create the button and pass the lat and lon parameters to the onClick function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html to just

```
<button 
  onClick="GetDirs(' + location[i].latitude + ', ' + location[i].longitude + ')"
>Directions</button>
```

And your function now is just

```
function GetDirs(sitelat,sitelon)
{
    var userlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(userlat, userlon); 
    var sitelatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(sitelat, sitelon);

    // continue to get directions from userlatlng to sitelatlng

} //GetDirs
```